# Using multiple Custom TableViewCell for UITableView

Tags: uitableview

I have 4 to 5 sections in the `UITableView` and each section I would like use different custom `UITableViewCell`.

Assigning cell under delegate function

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

But how do I assign differnt cells for different sections of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use index path for identifying different sections and different implementation for different sections-.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
         // Have custom implementation for first section
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1) {
         // Have custom implementation for second section and similarly others
    }
}
```